# multiple calls to $stmt->bind_param

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement, bindparam

I'm in a situation where I want to build a code which gets `$bindParam` variable in this format:

```
$bindParams = [$type1 => $param1, $type2 => $param2, ... ]
```

I wanna build some code that dynamically adds that parameters to the prepared statement.
This is the code which I built so far :

```
$mysql = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "db1");
$stmt = $mysql->prepare($sql);
foreach($bindParams as $type => $data) {
    $stmt->bind_param($type, $data);
}
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
// and after perhaps twiddling with the result set, but this is not the case .....
```

For your instance

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table1 (name, age) VALUES (?,?);"
```

and

```
$bindParams = ["s" => "hello", "i" => 15]
```

**This does not always have this structure and it can change to for example `$bindParams = ["s" => "hello", "i" => 15, "d" => 22.5]` and so the `$sql` changes respectively.**

After the first time the compiler heads to `$stmt->bind_param($type, $data);` firefox flushes this error:

> Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in D:\PHP\tr.php on line 23

I know PDO support that as stated [here at the end of the page.](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp) but perhaps as you might expect Im not a fan of PDO so ;)
My other option is to use the `eval()` workarounds available in php but thats out of what I might think of.

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Show your `$query` and your `$bindParams`. If you have more than 1 of any type, it will overwrite each other, so you'll always end up with 1 of any type.

Comment: You cant put one param on 2 diferent calls for the same call. At first each you pass the name like `INSERT INTO table1 (name, age) VALUES ("hello", )` and `INSERT INTO table1 (name, age) VALUES (, 15)` You need to put 2 values at same

Comment: @ManuelRodriguezGil I know that .. yes .. is there any workarounds? Cause I cant put those values in one call. I am receiving that as an array from a function call.

Comment: If `$bindParams` always have the same structure you can do: `$stmt->bind_param('si', $bindParams["s"], $bindParams["i"]);`

Comment: @ManuelRodriguezGil no that is exactly the problem ;) for example one could call my function and pass this value to `$bindParams` : `$bindParams = ["s" => "hello", "i" => 15, "s" => "world"]` and so `$sql` changes respectively.

Comment: @ManuelRodriguezGil yeah thats possibly one of my wrong expectations. ok assume we add each element of that associative array (each pair) in one array element of another array like this: `$bindParams = [0 => ["s" => "world"], 1 => ["i" => 15], 2 => ["s" => "world"]]` :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sadly `mysqli` doesn't support this. Calling the function over and over again overwrites the values, so you're only binding one param when you clearly have more.

There's a couple of ways to get around this

1. Switch to PDO. You can make one bind per function call with that
2. Bind the params as one aggregate using [call_user_func_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php)

   ```
    $sqltype = '';
    $sqldata = [];
    foreach($bindParams as $type => $data) {
        $sqltype .= $type;
        $sqldata[] = &$data; // MUST be a reference
    }
    array_unshift($sqldata, $sqltype); // prepend the types
    call_user_func_array([$stmt, 'bind_param'], $sqldata);
   ```

**PHP 8.1 and later**

An even easier solution is to use a convention in PHP 8.1 where you place your data into an indexed (unkeyed) array and let mysqli bind it all as strings

```
$stmt->execute([$firstname, $lastname, $userid]);
```

Functionally equivalent to

```
$stmt->bind_param('sss', $firstname, $lastname, $userid);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: I dont see any example data, such as 's' for string in sqltype

Comment: @ValterEkholm The example data is in the question itself. And I admit my original example really only works for the OP's code

Answer (score 23):

I had the same problem, and found an answer much simplier:

```
$array_of_values = array( "Brasil", "Argentina" );
$types = "ss";
$mysqli_stmt->bind_param( $types, ...$array_of_values );
```

This is called "argument unpacking", and is available since PHP 5.6

- http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/migration56.new-features.php

Comment: Its been a long time since the time I was struggling with this problem. But thanks for your thoughts. I will apply your solution and see if it works as soon as I face the problem again.

Comment: it wasn't obvious to me that the three dots were a defined operator, because two or three dots (admittedly as a suffix rather than prefix) can sometimes just leave a sentence hanging, even in code...

Answer (score 0):

I use something like this to do dynamic procedure calls.

Example Call:

```
    $mapi = new MySQLIAPI($con);
    $mapi->BeginProc();
    $mapi->AddParameter("user", $usern, "s");
    $mapi->AddParameter("email", $email, "s");
    $mapi->AddParameter("passwd", $pwd, "s");
    $id = $mapi->CallProc("ij_create_user");
    $id = $id[0];

    if(isset($id['mysql_error']) || isset($id["error"])){
      return "error";
    }
    return $id["id"];
```

Example Class:

```
class MySQLIAPI
{
    private $con = null;
    private $Variables = null;
    private $values = null;
    private $types = null;
    private $vQu = null;
    private $stmt = null;
    function __construct($dbc)
    {
        $this->con = $dbc;
            $this->Variables = [];
        $this->values = [];
        $this->types = [];
        $this->vQu = [];
    }
    function BeginProc()
    {
        $this->stmt = $this->con->stmt_init(); // initialize statement
    }

    function AddParameter($key, $val, $type)
    {
        $this->Variables[] = "@" . $key;
        $this->values[]    = $val;
        $this->types[]     = $type;
        $this->vQu[]       = "?";
    }

    //KeyPair is v = the value, t = the type s or d
    function CallProc($Proc) {
      $out_var = null;

      $call = "";
      if(sizeof($this->values) > 0)
        $call = "CALL ".$Proc."(".implode(",", (array)$this->vQu).")";
      else
        $call = "CALL ".$Proc."()";

     if($this->stmt->prepare($call));//call stored procedure with database server session variable
     {
       if(sizeof($this->values) > 0) {
         $params = array_merge(array(implode("", $this->types)), $this->values);
         call_user_func_array(array($this->stmt, 'bind_param'), $this->refValues($params));
       }

       $this->stmt->execute();
       $result = $this->stmt->get_result();

       /* Error Checking */
       $mySQLiError = mysqli_stmt_error($this->stmt);
       if ($mySQLiError != "") {
         $this->resetStmt();
         $this->stmt->close();
         $this->stmt = null;
         return array('mysql_error' => $mySQLiError);
       }

       while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
       {
         $out_var[] = $row;
       }
       $result->free();
       while($this->stmt->more_results())
       {
         $this->stmt->next_result();
       }

       $this->resetStmt();
       $this->stmt->close();
       $this->stmt = null;
     }

     return $out_var;
    }
    private function refValues($arr)
    {
        if (strnatcmp(phpversion(), '5.3') >= 0) //Reference is required for PHP 5.3+
            {
            $refs = array();
            foreach ($arr as $key => $value)
                $refs[$key] =& $arr[$key];
            return $refs;
        }
        return $arr;
    }
    private function resetStmt()
    {
        //Reset Params
        $this->Variables = array();
        $this->values    = array();
        $this->types     = array();
        $this->vQu       = array();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `mapi` there :| Please verify your answer

Comment: sorry about that @TechJS mapi is just the variable of the instance of the class MySQLIAPI